# Count the number of events between two (or more) different login periods

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to count the number of events occured for each user between each login. The login are stored at one table, and the other events are stored at another.

So if a user logged-in at `2019-10-03 10:00:00` then any events that occured after that time will be grouped and counted towards that specific time until a new event occurs (e.g: `2019-11-04 11:00:00`) and then we'll count according to the new time.

Meaning that for `2019-10-03 10:00:00` we'll count all values between `2019-10-03 10:00:00` and `2019-11-04 11:00:00` and for `2019-11-04 11:00:00` we count anything above it.

Another way of looking at it:

user_login:

```
User | Login_Timestamp
1    | 2019-10-03 10:00:00
1    | 2019-11-03 14:44:00
1    | 2019-14-03 08:01:11
```

user_events:

```
User | ... | EventTimestamp
1    | ... | 2019-10-03 10:01:00
1    | ... | 2019-10-03 10:10:00
1    | ... | 2019-11-03 13:10:00
1    | ... | 2019-11-03 14:45:11
1    | ... | 2019-11-03 14:46:11
1    | ... | 2019-14-03 10:10:00
```

The output I would like to get is:

```
User | LoginTimestamp       | NumberOfEvents
1    | 2019-10-03 10:00:00  | 3
1    | 2019-11-03 14:44:00  | 2
1    | 2019-14-03 08:01:11  | 1
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using transposition:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT user, 
      loginTimestamp AS loginTimestampStart, 
      LEAD(loginTimestampStart) OVER(PARTITION BY user
                                     ORDER BY loginTimestamp) AS loginTimestampEnd
  FROM user_login
)
SELECT c.user, c.loginTimestampStart, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEvents
FROM cte c
JOIN user_events e
  ON c.user = e.user
 AND e.EventTimestamp >= c.loginTimestampStart
 AND (e.EventTimestamp < c.loginTimestampEnd OR c.loginTimestampEnd IS NULL)
GROUP BY c.user, c.loginTimestampStart
```

Comment: LEAD was the lead I was looking for ! :)